# What programme to use for large database (numbers) later to use for calculation, analysis and graphic?

Tags: database, excel, graph, analysis

Currently, I am working on a folder of Excel which consist of database (number) size of 1.34GB 63 files and growing. I can continue to work in Excel but I have to separate one large piece of file into several sub-files which is not very convenience and sometimes confusing when it come to calculation, analysis and graphic.

I wonder if there is any programme or programming software that I learn and have a lot function/formula/etc like the Excel.

Or

Is there any more effective way to use Excel?

Please feel free to ask the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I would consider importing the Excel data into a database.  This may offer more flexibility.  You will still be able to do calculations and graphs/charts.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Excel_Automation.aspx

Make sure the Excel files are as small as possible.  Take a look at:

http://www.ehow.com/how_2252595_reduce-size-excel-files.html